# Ulm and Frattini Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian group. We define $U(A)=\cap (nA), n\in \mathbb N$ be the Ulm subgroup of $A$. The Frattini subgroup of $A$ is $\Phi(A)=\cap(pA)$ ($p\in \mathbb P$). I was trying to show that taking repeatedly (a countable times at most) the Frattini subgroup of $A$, let's call this $\Phi^\omega(A)$, lead us to the Ulm subgroup of $A$.

Clearly, $\Phi^\omega(A)\leq U(A)$, since the $n$th application of $\Phi$ is contained in $\cap (pq...tA)$, $p,q,...,t\in \mathbb P$.

I have trouble showing the other inclusion. If, for instance, $\cap (pqA)$ is contained in $\cap (q(\cap(pA)))$, then all my trouble would be solved.

Any hints or ideas?

Edit: [First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWy1s.jpg),  [Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHLFb.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure it is true? It seems like $\Phi(A)=0$ is not very hard to happen, so I worry that $\Phi^\omega(A)$ might actually be pretty small. I didn't study torsion-free groups well enough, but it seems like if some exts don't vanish, it should be easy to get $U(A) = \Phi(A) \neq \Phi^2(A)$.

Comment: Laszlo Fuchs, "Infinite Abelian Groups", Vol. 1, pag. 28.
He says that the subfunctor of identity $F$ (that to each abelian group assigns the Frattini subgroup of the same group) can be iterated transfinitely to $F^\omega$ leading to the functor that take every abelian group in their Ulm subgroup.

Comment: That is exactly what you are doing, so presumably it is true. :-) I think your pq equality is the key. I'll think about why it is true.

Comment: Maybe these pages of the Fuchs could be of some help.





http://imageshack.us/a/img708/6707/schermatadel20130520232.jpg
http://imageshack.us/a/img197/6707/schermatadel20130520232.jpg

Comment: If $RS:=\{rs:r\in R,s\in S\}$ then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{r\in R} r\left(\bigcap_{s\in S}sA\right)$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{x\in RS}xA$ are equal no? Ambient multiplication by a fixed scalar in a module is in particular a function, and applications of functions distribute through unions and intersections.

Comment: @anon I think that, also in case you described, we just have one inclusion (namely, $r(\cap (sA))\leq \cap(rsA)$, $r$ fixed). I really can't see the other =(.

Comment: Err, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proposition**

$\cap\{(pqA)\,|\,p, q\in\mathbb{P}\}=\cap\{q(\cap\{pA\, |\,p\in \mathbb{P}\})\, |\, q\in \mathbb{P}\}$

**Proof**

Assume for a contradiction that

$\cap\{q(\cap\{pA\, |\,p\in \mathbb{P}\})\, |\, q\in \mathbb{P}\}<\cap\{(pqA)\,|\,p, q\in\mathbb{P}\}$

and let $b\in\cap\{(pqA)\,|\,p, q\in\mathbb{P}\}$ such that $b\notin \cap\{q(\cap\{pA\, |\,p\in \mathbb{P}\})\, |\, q\in \mathbb{P}\}$.

There are $r,q\in \mathbb{P}$ such that $(b=rqc\, \, (c\in A) \implies qc\notin\Phi(G))$ 
or in other words $(b=rqc \implies \exists s \in \mathbb{P} : qc\notin sA)$.

Obviously $q\neq s$ and by hypothesis we can write $b=rsx=rqc\,\, (x,y\in A)$.

Then $r(qc-sx)=0$, therefore $(qc\notin sA)$ $(qc-sx)\in A[r]-\{ 0\}$.

If $r\neq s$, $A[r]=sA[r]$ and there is a $z\in A[r]$ such that $qc-sx=sz$. So $qc\in sA$, a contradiction.

Now, $r=s$ and the following implication works

$(*)$ $b=qrc\,\, (c\in A) \implies qc\notin rA$

Now, since $r\neq q$, $A[r]=qA[r]$ and it exists an $a\in A[r]$ such that $qc-rx=qa$ (take in mind that $(qc-sx)\in A[r]-\{0\}$).

So we know that $q(c-a)=rx\in rA$ and $b=r^2 x=rq(c-a)$ and this contradicts $(*)$.
$\square$

**Theorem**

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\Phi^n(G)=U^n(G)$, where

$U^n:= \cap\{(p_1p_2...p_n)A\, |\, (p_1,...,p_n)\in \mathbb{P}^n\}$ $(n\geq1)$

**Proof**

We argue by induction on $n$. The above proposition proves the case when $n=2$ (it works fine also if we assume $n=1$ as starting point).

Let $n\geq 3$

So we have $\Phi^{n-1}(G)=U^{n-1}(G)$. Then $\Phi^n(G)=\Phi(U^{n-1}(G))$.

Assume now that $\Phi^n(G)$ is strictly contained in $U^n(G)$. Hence it exists an $b\in U^n(G)$ and $b\notin \Phi^n(G)$.

In other words, we have that exists a prime $q$ such that the following implication hold:

$b=qc\, \, (c\in G) \implies c\notin U^{n-1}(G)$ ($\exists q_1, q_2, ...,q_{n-1}: c\notin (q_1...q_{n-1})G$).

However $b$ is in $U^n(G)$ and so we can write $b=q(q_1...q_{n-1}x)$, a contradiction. $\square$

**Corollary**

$\Phi^\omega(G) = U(G)$